# Recode factor based on values from a string

Tags: r, forcats

I have a (very) large dataset, which has been imported from a server without any formatting. The formatting has been given to me in a text file. Let's say I have a variable in the dataframe, is there any way I can format it as a factor with the levels as defined in the string.

Take for example, a dataframe `df` which has a variable `value` that can take either 1, 2 or 3, which should be coded as defined in the string `format`:

```
format <- "
    1 = 'Declined'
    2 = 'Registered'
    3 = 'Randomised'
"

df %>%
  mutate(value = as.factor(value) %>%
           fct_recode(format))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
format <- c(Declined = "1", Registered = "2", Randomised = "3")
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(value = fct_recode(value, !!!format))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(value = factor(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2)))
```